# Can I insert text alongside filter results?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to insert a text phrase alongside any data that is displayed after my autofilter is run on Sheet3.

If there are differences greater than `$2` I want to display the following text in column L on whatever row my first result is in.

> Please review 'Differences' & advise of any changes in participant status, contribution amounts, etc.

If there are no results, no descriptor text is needed.

Column A is the person's name, and column K is the "difference." Column L is where I wanted my notes to go.

My assumption was that after running the autofilter, I could find out if there was any text in Column A (after the header in A3) and if so, display my pre-made notes in the notes section under Column L.

Current code is as follows:

```vb
Worksheets("Sheet3").Select
Range("A2:L300").AutoFilter Field:=12, VisibleDropDown:=False, Criteria1:=">2", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="<-2"
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet3")
If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsText(ws.Range("A3:A300")) = True Then
    ws.Range("L3") = "Please review 'Differences' & advise of any changes in participant status, contribution amounts, etc."
End If
```

This is my best effort based on copying code that is close to what I am attempting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running a filter you can use `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` to get any visible rows, and loop over them:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, rngVis As Range, c As Range
    
    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet3")
    
    With ws.Range("A2:L300")
        .AutoFilter Field:=12, VisibleDropDown:=False, _
             Criteria1:=">2", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="<-2"
        On Error Resume Next  'ignore error if no visible rows
        Set rngVis = .Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        On Error GoTo 0       'stop ignoring errors
    End With
    
    If Not rngVis Is Nothing Then    'any visible rows?
        For Each c In rngVis.Cells   'loop over visible cells in ColA
            If Len(c.Value) > 0 Then 'cell has a value?
                c.EntireRow.Columns("L").Value = _
                  "Please review 'Differences' & advise of any changes " & _
                  "in participant status, contribution amounts, etc."
            End If
        Next c
    End If

End Sub
```